# When I launch a website with Python Behave, sometimes i get cookies tab

Tags: python, terminal, python-behave

So I am currently working on VSCode with Python Selenium Behave. I have noticed this strange behavior.

1. There is some particular terminal in which if I execute the "behave features\app.feature", it launches an instance of the webpage, where I get the traditional "Accept All Cookies" tab.
2. But when I execute the same "behave features\app.feature " command in another particular terminal, an instance of the browser is launched, where I do not get the "Accept All Cookies" tab.

I would like to know which particular terminal runs a web driver instance with and without "Accept All Cookies". Absolutely nothing changes with the file structure, but I still notice the above 2 behaviors. I don't have any saved Firefox profiles either. I am unable to understand why this happens.